# Storing report results, MySql or MongoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, entity-attribute-value

I have a bunch of reports that I am generating on a weekly and monthly basis.  I started to create a MySQL database  but then realized I will need to either have tables with tons of columns, and possibly adding them later on.  I will then need to update the code every time I add a new column.

I could use an EAV model, or some kind of key/value model, but this would be slow, right?

So then I remember an article about MongoDB, being a 'document' database.  The reports are documents, so is this an ideal solution to my problem?  It seems too easy?

Comment: "I will then need to update the code every time I add a new column" - probably not. Just run your query so that it outputs the columns you need, and then detect them in your code. This can help you render both headers and data rows. You can have meta-tables that convert column names into pretty column names too. Since you are already using MySQL, I don't think there is any need to switch to Mongo.

Comment: It's a bit to broad to answer completely, but from what I can see, MongoDB seems quite suitable for you. You might want to take  a class at [MongoDB university](https://university.mongodb.com). Vote for closing nevertheless, because the question is too broad.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I can understand what you are saying about the broadness of the question.  However sometimes it is hard to ask a question about a concept, or the right or wrong way of doing a task, whilst being specific.

Comment: @EquinoxMatt Can I somehow improve my answer for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your reports tend to have different data structures once in a while then MongoDB is the way to go. You could also store your reports on the filesystem in the XML or JSON formats. You can also serialize your reports to JSON and store them in a MySQL database (this way you can handle different data structures without the need to alter the table). There are many ways to achieve what you're describing. Keep in mind searchability of your reports that may vary based on the choice you make.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   I did initially think about storing them in JSON format within the MySQL database, but then I realise searching them would be a complete pain.  That being said,  I can't think of any reason why I would need to search for the report contents, just the meta values (date generated) etc.   If i did need to search the report values,  then MongoDB sounds like it could be a viable option?

Comment: Sure, since mongo uses json format out of the box. But is it worth the overhead? You can pretty easy search your filesystem too.

Comment: @MK: Well, due to various caching techniques I'd say that MongoDB is faster than the filesystem when querying JSON. Furthermore, a highly available filesystem is not as easy to implement as a HA MongoDB – and manual data partitioning is a pain in the neck.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg sure, there are many "pro" and "contras" for each of the approaches.